# How do I rebase a timeseries in Looker Studio after changing date range?

Tags: time-series, dashboard, finance, looker-studio

I am working with plotting multiple financial timeseries in the same chart, data source is Google Sheets. When adjusting the date range for my data, it correctly shows the time series limited to the desired interval. However, since I'm comparing multiple timeseries (e.g. a stock and an index) I need them to start from the same value which is as simple as rebasing them by dividing the current step with the first step in the time series, x/x[0]. The first step then always being the first in the date *range*.

[Before changing date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO45i.png)
[After changing date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6G1q.png)

Here both time series shall shall start at 1, even after changing range. Since I cannot find a way to use data at a specific index in the time series, I got stuck with the formulas quickly. I have just started with Looker Studio.

Complete time series example:

| Date | Series 1 | Series 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1.2 | 1.4 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1.3 | 1.6 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1.4 | 1.8 |
| 2023-01-06 | 1.5 | 2.0 |

Then, when changing date range in Looker studio to 2023-01-03, the plotted data shall be rebased to again start from 1.0, this is achieved by dividing all values with the first in the range, resulting in the table below:

Desired result after date range change, note that they again start from the same value (1.0).

| Date | Series 1 | Series 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-03 | 1.0 (1.2/1.2) | 1.0 (1.4/1.4) |
| 2023-01-04 | 1.08 (1.3/1.2) | 1.14 (1.6/1.4) |
| 2023-01-05 | 1.17 (1.4/1.2) | 1.29 (1.8/1.4) |
| 2023-01-06 | 1.25 (1.5/1.2) | 1.43 (2.0/1.4) |

A minimal example with two dummy timeseries shown in the same chart is available [here](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/23e190ab-8ed8-4a31-a886-7013f6db3fcf/page/58KbD) in a public editable version.

The questions basically boils down to: How can I access the first timeseries row in a Looker formula?

Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to rebase a timeseries chart in Looker Studio after changing its date range? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Further clarification and link to public editable dashboard added.